# How to get the min and the max index where a pandas column has the same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'step': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'val': [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]})
```

I would like to get the 1st and last `step` for each of the sequence of `1`s in the `val` column.
Explanation:

- The first sequence of ones happens at steps `1,2,3` -> first `step` is `1` last `step` is 3
- The second sequence of ones happens at step 6 -> first `step` is `6` last `step` is 6
- The last sequence of ones happens at step 8 -> first `step` is `8` last `step` is 8

So the output is the list `[1,3,6,6,8,8]`

Any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: shouldn't the output rather be `[1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 8]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a `groupby` aggregation, flatten using numpy and convert to list:

```
# compute groups of consecutive numbers
group = foo['val'].ne(foo['val'].shift()).cumsum()

out = (foo
 .loc[foo['val'].eq(1), 'step']         # keep step only where vale is 1
 .groupby(group).agg(['first', 'last']) # get first and last
 .to_numpy().ravel().tolist()           # reshape
)
```

output: `[1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.assign(col1=foo.val.diff().eq(1).cumsum()).query("val==1")\
    .groupby(['col1'],as_index=False).step.agg(['first','last'])\
    .stack().tolist()
```

output: [1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 8]